# cakephp3.0 pagination giving error for join table

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.0 and trying to pagination result set from two tables

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'ModifierGroups.id',
        'ModifierGroups.name',
        'ModifierGroups.type',
        'ModifierGroups.house_id',
        'Houses.name',               
    ),
    'conditions' => $search_filter,
    'limit' => 18,
    'order' => ['ModifierGroups.name' => 'ASC'], 
    'recursive'=>-1,      
);

$this->paginate('ModifierGroups')
```

but it's giving me this error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Houses.name' in 'field list'

ModelTable

```
$this->belongsTo('Houses', [
    'foreignKey' => 'house_id'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use contain to include 'Houses', associated models are no longer lazy loaded. recursive is also gone in CakePHP3

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations